# Struts 2 global-exception-mappings for HTTP error codes

Tags: java, exception, struts2, error-handling, http-error

Is it possible to handle the error pages which defined in `web.xml`, as the `global-exception-mappings` in Struts 2 actions.
For example, instead of

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/common/jsp/FilkeNotFine.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Define something like below:

```
<global-exception-mppings>
    <exception-mapping ErrorCode="404" result="internernal-error" /> 
</global-exception-mppings>
```

Are there any plugin or interceptor that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse you can

```
<global-results>
  <result name="error">/common/jsp/FilkeNotFine.jsp</result>
</global-results>

<global-exception-mappings>
  <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

the interceptor is `exception` defined in the package `struts-default` and the part of the  `defaultStack`.

Comment: are you sure? where do we define http error codes. for example error 404>file not find. 
400>bad request

Comment: This is a common error handling by the exception thrown in your application, codes you may send to the response.

Comment: Then I should redirect to different pages in my jsp page base on error code!

Comment: You can't redirect, just send the error and escape, the web container will handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and with my own knowledge, IMHO there's no way to do that. Struts2 is not the one throwing 404, it's the web-server. 
Struts2 will throw the exception.

RomanC's answer explains clear enough on how to handle exception, but what you're looking forward to, can't be met 100%.

Instead you can try something like this :

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/common/jsp/my404.action</location>
</error-page>
```

and then you can have my404 mapped to some action in your struts xml.

Although I'm not certain that it may work, I guess it's server dependent. 
IMHO dynamic resource can't be used in such cases since the server requires for that file to be physically present.

If that happens, you can simply create a file named my404.action in your web-root and then struts2 will handle the rest, if you understand what I'm talking about.

Not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You must change first the devMode into false from your struts.xml so you can now use your 404 Page.

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```